# How to handle an exception in an event?

Tags: c#, vb.net

So - I have this external assembly that I'm using. It fires an event `DataReceived`. Then I'm doing some database operations which may fail due to problems with the data or because of some errors in the code. It would be great if I could "bubble up" the exception into the GUI. In my case I would need a blocking call to the GUI because of the way the assembly works. I'm not sure if this is a good idea but right now that's the only thing that comes to mind based on how the external code works.

The assembly assumes that if the callback (the event) returned safely then the data was processed succesfully - which may not be the case. Of course I would have to deal with the error in *some way* but that would mean that the server on the other side would always assume that the data was handled correctly.

My questions are:

- Can I throw the exception *into* the GUI? If so, how?
- How can I handle the exception in my event so that the assembly doesn't think I processed the data? Do I need some kind of blocking call/exception *into* the GUI? (Is this even possible?)
- On a side note: Isn't that assembly *broken by design* somehow? Why would it automatically assume that everything went fine just based on if the callback returned?

Comment: Are you looking for some architectural guidance? Or are you trying to solve a specific programming error?

Comment: A good idea would be to write a better question.  Then you would not get downvoted and closed.

Comment: You are right. It was in the middle of the night and my brain already went to sleep - so my questions were not really obvious. I tried to be more specific now.

I think I'm mainly searching for architectural guidance because I never had an error that I had to catch outside of my own program flow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is *broken by design*. If you receive the event you'll get informed that something has changed in the source. Now you should only do what is needed to get the informations you need from the source and do any further processing decoupled from the source. For that purpose I would within the event handler simply grab the data (maybe from the source; maybe from the event args) and put them into a [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx). Within my class another Task is running that using the [`BlockingCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) the retrieve the elements out of this queue to process them. If anything fails, simply call `Invoke()` to the gui thread and inform the user about what happened.

Ah, and another approach instead of using `ConcurrentQueue` would be to use [Rx](http://www.introtorx.com). With that you can [subscribe to an event](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc7) and observe it on a different thread by using [`ObserveOn()`](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html#SubscribeOnObserveOn) which would lead to nearly the same (in this case) but using a more LINQish syntax.